# Can Fresnel zone plates be used as collimators

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, diffraction, home-experiment

I quite often use the principle in physics that (outside of thermodynamics), all laws of physics are time-reversible. And so, when looking at collimating microwave light, I though that it might be possible to use a Fresnel zone plate to act as a collimator rather than a focuser. However, when looking at this situation, I realised that actually there should logically be multiple orders of diffraction patterns, one resulting in a focused point, one resulting in a continuation of the initial beam, and presumably further orders as well. So far I have just been considering eliminating the focused order by blocking off the focal point, but should I be worrying about extra orders and extra effects? (I'm hoping not, I already made the zone plate!)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are right, there will be some intensity in several different orders no matter how you set up your experiment. Whether to worry about them or not is up to you, but where they overlap there will be interference and the resulting intensity patter will show these interference effects. You haven't given any dimensions, but if you are using the collimator to produce a fairly parallel beam from a small source, then distance is your friend. All the other orders will diverge, or converge, focus, then diverge, at some point, so the interference within your collimated beam will weaken far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an off-axis Fresnel zone plate, more or less equivalent to a far off-axis parabolic lens, then it is possible to collimate light from a point monochromatic source, *without* producing multiple orders.

[image: Fresnel collimator]
 The point is that if the geometry is chosen so that the angle of any higher order diffracted beams would drop below the surface of the plate, there won't be any higher order beams.